# How to get username of user not in Discord guild?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working with discord.py, and
for example, this code:

```
m = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id) 
m.name
```

returns the username, but this only works for members in the guild in which the command with the given code was used.
How to get the name of a user if they are not in the guild, but for whom we have a `user_id`?

Comment: What guild? what did you try? Which api / package are you using?

Comment: Have you tried `Client.get_user(user_id)`?

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Client.get_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) to retrieve a user from the user cache. Otherwise, if your bot doesn't share any guilds with the user, you can use [`Client.fetch_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user), which is an API call and a coroutine. You can then use the [`User.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.name) attribute as before.